# How to get the employees and their levels reporting to the manager directly and indirectly without using a CTE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

```
employee_id    manager_id
1               1
2               1
3               1
4               2
5               1
6               3   
7               2
8               2
9               3
10              2
```

How to get the `emanager`'s subordinates and their levels without using a CTE?

Because we have to implement the same in MySQL.

Output should be like this

```
@Managerid = 1

manager_id          employee_id     Level
1                       2               1 
1                       3               1
1                       5               1
2                       4               2
2                       7               2
2                       8               2
2                       10              2
3                       9               3
```

level 1 is direct reporting to the manager in question; level 2 and 3... so on are indirect reporting to the manager's reporting employee (also manager for other employees)

Comment: Is there a fixed maximum number of levels?

Comment: No Sir, it have to be dynamic variable.

Comment: And why do you need the exact same query in both platforms? We have things like stored procedures so that each platform can solve the query problem in the best way *for that platform* and the application doesn't have to care.

Comment: I suggest you read [How to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Any suggestion, idea............ will be most helpfull.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration.

```
create table #employee (
            EmployeeID int,
            ManagerID int
        )
insert #employee 
    values
        (1, 1), 
        (2, 1), 
        (3, 1 ),
        (4, 2 ),
        (5, 1 ),
        (6, 3),
        (7, 2 ),
        (8, 2 ),
        (9, 3 ),
        (10, 2)

declare @RootEmployeeID int = 1
declare @lev int = 0
declare @rowcount int = 0
declare @oldcount int = 0

create table #employeetree (
        EmployeeID int,
        ManagerID int,
        lev int
    )


insert #employeetree
    (EmployeeID, ManagerID, lev)
    select  EmployeeID,
            ManagerID,
            0
        from #employee
        where
            EmployeeID = @RootEmployeeID
select @rowcount = COUNT(*) from #employeetree

while @rowcount > @oldcount
begin

    insert #employeetree
        (EmployeeID, ManagerID, lev)
        select  e.EmployeeID,
                e.ManagerID,
                et.lev + 1
            from #employeetree et
            join #employee e on
                e.ManagerID = et.EmployeeID
                and e.ManagerID <> e.EmployeeID -- skip cases where you are your own manager (otherwise you go infinite loop)
            where
                et.lev = @lev

    -- This works for both, instead of using @@ROWCOUNT (SQL Server) or ROW_COUNT() (MySql):
    set @lev = @lev + 1
    set @oldcount = @rowcount

    select @rowcount = COUNT(*) from #employeetree
end

select * from #employeetree

drop table #employeetree
drop table #employee
```